# Download ism video for offline playback

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, smooth-streaming

I have a windows 10 UWP app where I allow users to stream ism videos using [Smooth Streaming Client SDK](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1e7d4700-7fa8-49b6-8a7b-8d8666685459). This works without any problems.

Now I need to give users an option to download these videos so that they can play it offline. On a high level, I understand that the video and audio are stored as separate fragments of 1 second each.

So how do I download this video and make it in a playable format?

Comment: Depends on whether they are encrypted, and where they are hosted.

Comment: Is this problem solved? If yes, could someone please enlighten me on the solution. I'm also facing same issue now.

Comment: @Sandeep: Couldn't figure this out. So as a workaround, I downloaded mpd streams. You can easily download the entire audio and video streams in this case.

Comment: @Ferdin Thanks. :)